# Ошибка с cout, E0439 и C2679

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

Только начинаю изучать и не понимаю, что не так с cout.
Описание ошибок на сайте MS не дали новой информации.

Oтсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам.
Бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "std::string" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Person 
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Person> staff;
    staff.push_back({ "Ivan", "Ivanov", 25 });
    staff.push_back({ "Petr", "Tsyplakov", 32 });

    cout << staff[0].name;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Похоже, вы забыли `#include <string>`, в котором и объявлена перегрузка оператора `<<` для строки..

Comment: @Arhad Всё верно, скопилировалось. Спасибо)